# SOLR 4.1.0 - Date Query between fields

Tags: solr

I have SOLR Core with policy data, including two date fields: EffectiveDate and ExpirationDate.

I want to write a SOLR query that finds policies that, given a date d, were open on on that date so if this was SQL the WHERE clause would be: d BETWEEN EffectiveDate AND ExpirationDate

I would like to do this without changing the SOLR core

I have tried the following with no luck:

```
EffectiveDate[2020-01-01T00:00:00Z TO *] AND ExpirationDate[* TO 2020-01-01T00:00:00Z]
EffectiveDate:[2020-01-01T00:00:00Z TO *] AND ExpirationDate:[* TO 2020-01-01T00:00:00Z]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've switched your intervals around.

EffectiveDate should be checked from any time until the datetime you're checking for, and expiration date from the current datetime to any time.

```
EffectiveDate:[* TO 2020-01-01T00:00:00Z] AND ExpirationDate:[2020-01-01T00:00:00Z TO *]
```

This will give you those that were active at `2020-01-01T00:00:00Z`.

Otherwise you'll only get those that had `2020-01-01T00:00:00Z` in both `EffectiveDate` and `ExpirationDate`.